# Nomenclature for all parts of a progressbar

Tags: gui-design, terminology, progress-bar

I'm looking to get a name  for all off the different parts of a progressbar.

e.g.

```
Loading [ =====>   ] 1/20 (5%) done
```

I want to know what name can be given to the following parts:

"`Loading`" label?

"`[      ]`" the body?

"`===`" progress line?

"`>`" progress header

"`1/20`" Value

"`(5%)`" Percentage label?

"`done`" suffix/trailer?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to communicate these terms with the user, or just constructing a way to talk about it on your own/with developers or designers?

Comment: @maxathousand I am making a progressbar API and I want to describe the various parts that can be customized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions.

`"Loading"` status indicator

`"[      ]"` container

`"==="` progress indicator

`">"` progress pointer

`"1/20"` Fraction completed

`"(5%)"` Percentage completed

`"done"` completion indicator